J2Store & Joomla 4 pagination loosing filter selections
I have a site where the J2Store & Pagination have stopped working together.
If you go to https://www.titusomega.com/antiques-sold/antiques there are 10 pages of results.
-> Search on the left for 'WMF' the search is added to the URL
-> Scroll to the end of the list, you can see there are only 3 pages of results.
Now if you click on page 2 the filters are lost from the query string and we are back to the full 10 pages of results.
Does any one know how to fix this or where I should start looking?
Thanks
S :)
